# How to diagnose when some computers on same network cannot connect to an external site

Tags: networking, vpn

Looking for some help on how to diagnose this problem, or even pointers to tools that can help me figure out what is happening.

In my LAN at home we have three computers, call them A, B, and C.  Computer C is connected to my work network through a VPN.  Whilst I was working on a blog entry on computer A, computer A suddenly lost access to my site.  Computer B cannot access it either.  However, computer C, which is on my LAN, but connected to my workplace's VPN, can connect to the site properly.

This tells me that the site itself is up, since I can access it.  The fact that computer C can access it, albeit through a VPN, is what has me confused.

Pinging the site from A or B yields lost packets, if I use IP address or domain name.  I've tried traceroute, and it hangs after 6 or so hops.  However, that is the extent of my networking mojo.

What would be the best approach to diagnose this?

As an added test, I tried accessing it from my phone over the celular network, and that too worked fine.

Comment: There are lots of options here - you could be blocked, could be a routing issue that is localised to your ISP.  Can you [edit] and add the traceroutes from the working and non working systems?

Comment: Problem seems to have been resolved on its own.

The routing issue local to my ISP makes the most sense to me; if this reoccurs I'll add the traceroutes.

Thanks!

Comment: Vote to close as it can no longer be reproduced/ has fixed itself.

Comment: Am I able to close this myself?